# if statement not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

Im building a log in for my website I have this if statement:

```
$application = 'home';
    $this->user_model->loggedin() == TRUE || redirect($application);


    $rules = $this->user_model->_rules;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {
          if ($this->user_model->login() !== FALSE) {
            redirect('home');
            echo 'success';
        }  else {
           echo 'fail'; 
        }

    }
```

For some reason it dose not run the else when I present with the condition == FALSE which would be entering wrong email and password. either way i get the message success am I missing something here ?

here is the function login in user_model if it helps, cant figure this one out any help will be appreciated.

```
public function login() {
    $user = $this->get_by(array(
        'email_address' => $this->input->post('email_address'),
        'password' => $this->hash($this->input->post('password'))
            ), TRUE);

    if (count($user)) {
        // log in user
        $data = array(
            'first_name' => $user->first_name,
            'last_name' => $user->last_name,
            'email_address' => $user->email_address,
            'id' => $user->id,
            'loggedin' => TRUE,
        );
      $this->session->set_userdata($data);   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your `login()` function. You either intended to return a TRUE or FALSE value depending on whether the login attempt succeeded (most likely), or you want to test against the session user data.

Comment: @user3035984 Sometimes all it takes is an extra pair of eyes

Comment: the eyes betray u sometime when you are up at 4 o'clock in the morning  :D